# Set vector/data frame column name from the contents of a variable

Tags: r

I am creating data frames that look like this:

```
            overlap   D     R
H3K9ME3    2635 209 91237
```

However I have some that are missing one or more columns. I need to create these columns and give the entries a value of `NA`. I tried to create a loop that could search for missing columns from a list (character vector) and fill in any that are missing.

Here is an example:

```
# this one is missing a column:
t_table<-structure(list(overlap = 14L, R = 59329L),
                     .Names = c("overlap","R"),
                     class = "data.frame", row.names = "H3K27ME3")
> t_table
         overlap     R
H3K27ME3      14 59329
```

In this loop, I try to search for and add the missing column:

```
t_table2<-t_table
  for(column in c("overlap","D","R")){
    if( ! column %in% colnames(t_table2)) t_table2<-cbind(t_table2,column=NA)
  }
  t_table2
```

However, the column name comes out as the literal character string of "column" and not as the value of `column`;

```
> t_table2
         overlap     R column
H3K27ME3      14 59329     NA
```

How do you set this up so that the resulting column name is the value of the object `column` and not "column", in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setNames` to dynamically set the column names for your new data frame:

```
t_table2<-t_table
for(column in c("overlap","D","R")){
    if( ! column %in% colnames(t_table2)) {
        t_table2<-setNames(cbind(t_table2,NA), c(names(t_table2), column))
}}

t_table2
         overlap     R  D
H3K27ME3      14 59329 NA
```